# How to conditionally assign values to tensor [masking for loss function]?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss, loss-function

I want to create a L2 loss function that ignores values (=> pixels) where the label has the value 0. The tensor `batch[1]` contains the labels while `output` is a tensor for the net output, both have a shape of `(None,300,300,1)`.

```
labels_mask = tf.identity(batch[1])
labels_mask[labels_mask > 0] = 1
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square((output-batch[1])*labels_mask))/tf.reduce_sum(labels_mask)
```

My current code yields to `TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment` (on the second line). What's the tensorflow-way to do this? I also tried to normalize the loss with `tf.reduce_sum(labels_mask)`, which I hope works like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to write it that way, you would have to use Tensorflow's `scatter` method for assignment. Unfortunately, tensorflow doesn't really support boolean indexing either (the new `boolean_select` makes it possible, but annoying). It would be tricky to write and difficult to read.

You have two options that are less annoying:

1. Use `labels_mask > 0` as a boolean mask and use Tensorflow's recent [boolean_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) function. Maybe this is the more tensorflow way, because it invokes arbitrarily specific functions.
2. Cast `labels_mask > 0` to float: `tf.cast(labels_mask > 0, tf.float32)`. Then, you can use it the way you wanted to in the final line of your code.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example how to apply boolean indexing and conditionally assign values to Variable:

```
a = tf.Variable(initial_value=[0, 0, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 0])
mask = tf.greater_equal(a, 2)  # [False False  True  True False  True  True False]
indexes = tf.where(mask)  # [[2] [3] [5] [6]], shape=(4, 1)
b = tf.scatter_update(a, mask, tf.constant(1500))
```

output:

```
[   0,    0, 1500, 1500,    1, 1500, 1500,    0]
```

Comment: @when trying to use that with eager tensor I get AttributeError: 'EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read', is there any way to use it with eager tensor?

Comment: has this `indexes = tf.where(mask)` line any purpose?